# C# Object Panels

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

The problem I'm having is where I can successfully use the RoomID of the Room object I've created, but not the panel. Here is the function where I set the label to the name of the room. (This is my Form1.cs)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Room ThisRoom = new Room(); 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        this.Text = "Aquinas College Master Controller";
    }

    private void roomDesignerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new RoomDesigner().Show();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        roomsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear();
        foreach (var Room in Global.Aquinas.Aquinas)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem NewItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(Room.RoomID);
            NewItem.Name = Room.RoomID;
            NewItem.Click += new EventHandler(ItemClick);
            roomsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(NewItem);
        }
    }

    void ItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripItem item = (ToolStripItem)sender;
        label2.Text = item.Name;
        foreach (var Room in Global.Aquinas.Aquinas)
        {
            if (Room.RoomID == item.Name)
            {
                ThisRoom = Room;
                break;
            }
        }
        Panel RoomPanel =  ThisRoom.Panel;
        RoomPanel.Size = new Size(607, 304);
        RoomPanel.Location = new Point(144, 27);
        RoomPanel.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.Controls.Add(RoomPanel);
    }
}
```

This is some of my code for the room object. (This is in Room.cs)

```
public class Room
{

    private List<CtrlComputer> _Computers;

    public List<CtrlComputer> Computers
    {
        get { return _Computers; }
        set { _Computers = value; }
    }

    private string _RoomID;

    public Room()
    {
        _Computers=new List<CtrlComputer>();
    }

    public string RoomID
    {
        get
        {
            return _RoomID;
        }

        set
        {
            _RoomID = value;
        }
    }

    public Panel Panel
    {
        get
        {
            return _Panel;
        }

        set
        {
            _Panel = value;
        }
    }

    private Panel _Panel;
}
```

And here is where I register the panel which I have just put my designs on, to a new room. (This is some of my RoomDesigner.cs)

```
public partial class RoomDesigner : Form
{
    Room NewRoom = new Room();
    Panel RoomDesignerPanel = new Panel();
    public RoomDesigner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RoomDesignerPanel.Size = new Size(607, 304);
        RoomDesignerPanel.Location = new Point(144, 27);
        RoomDesignerPanel.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.Controls.Add(RoomDesignerPanel);
        textBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        textBox1.Text = "Enter Computer ID Here";
        this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
        this.textBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Enter);
        textBox2.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        textBox2.Text = "Enter Room ID Here";
        this.textBox2.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_Leave);
        this.textBox2.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox2_Enter);
    }

    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Enter Computer ID Here";
            textBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "Enter Computer ID Here")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox1.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        }
    }
    private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "Enter Room ID Here";
            textBox2.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        }
    }

    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == "Enter Room ID Here")
        {
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox2.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        }
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CtrlComputer NewComputer = new CtrlComputer();
        NewComputer.ComputerID = textBox1.Text;
        NewComputer.Text = NewComputer.ComputerID;
        NewComputer.Parent = RoomDesignerPanel;
        RoomDesignerPanel.Controls.Add(NewComputer);
        NewRoom.Panel = RoomDesignerPanel;
        NewRoom.Add(NewComputer);
    }
```

When I try to reload that panel, the RoomID of that object is returned fine, yet the panel is not. Any ideas?

Edit: Sorry for the lack of clarity in my post, first posts aren't always easy.
The panel is created in the designer, but I tried `private Panel Panel1 = new Panel();` with no luck. My current problem is that in Form1.cs, the program will throw "Cannot access a disposed object", but I followed the guide here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82785s1h(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: Its a little difficult to say without seeing more of your code, but I think panel1 = ThisRoom.Panel; in that first code block may not be what you intended. Just as you got done setting the backcolor of panel1, you replace panel1 with another panel (potentially). If panel1 is part of your designer code, as I suspect, replacing that reference will do nothing. this.Controls contains the important reference to "panel1" as that is where the Form renders controls from.

Comment: Since I don't see any code creating any new Panel objects, I think that you only have a single Panel object being passed around (the one created by the designer code)

Comment: If you can post your (related) designer code and include what scopes the snippets above are in I or someone else may be able to help more

Comment: @SeanK Sorry about the missing information, but I'm not 100% sure which parts you'd need without including irrelevant code. My intention was to save the panel made in RoomDesigner to the newly created Room object, then find the room using it's unique ID, and set the panel on Form1, to the panel of the chosen room.

Comment: Ok, thats a little clearer. first problem is that when you set (in Form1) panel1 = anything, all you are doing is changing the panel1 reference created by the designer code, NOT what is on the form. The actual panel on the form remains the same. If you want to replace the panel on the form, you need to remove the current one from the form's Controls collection, and add the replacement panel to that same collection. The second problem I see is that I don't see any code that includes "new Panel()" where you create one of those panels that you plan to place on the form.

Comment: @SeanK I've tried to implement your suggestions with little success. I've updated the post with my "improvements". Again, thank you for your continued support.

Comment: @SeanK A little confused how I can set the reference for label2 equal to ThisRoom.RoomID, but not panel1 equal to ThisRoom.Panel?

Comment: Glad to help any way I can. First off, you aren't setting the label2 reference, you are setting the text property of that existing Label. You are doing something entirely different with the Panel. I will have an answer shortly explaining how that needs to work (you are close at this point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking to do is swap between a collection of Panel objects (kind of like your own version of TabPages). To do this you need to create each of the Panel objects (You do this in RoomDesigner, which is fine, but there is a catch: see * below). With that collection in hand, when you want to show it on the form, you need to remove the panel1 the designer code created (Controls.Remove(panel1)) and insert your new one (Controls.Add(RoomPanel)).

Since Controls utilize system resources, make sure to Dispose any control you will no longer use. Here is an example method:

```
    //Initial case where no room has been displayed yet and panel1 is still valid
    private Panel CurrentPanel = null;

    public void SwapPanel(Panel p)
    {
        //If no panel has been placed yet, get rid of the default one
        if (panel1 != null)
        {
            //we should never need the designer panel again, so dispose it
            panel1.Dispose();
            this.Controls.Remove(panel1);
        }
        else
        {
            //we may return to this panel later, so don't dispose it
            this.Controls.Remove(CurrentPanel);
        }
        CurrentPanel = p;
        this.Controls.Add(p);
    }
```

When you finally close out and no longer need your Panels stored in your Room collection, make sure to Dispose them. (However, if your whole program is exiting at that point then it doesn't matter, but do it anyway as good practice)

*When you close any RoomDesigner form (or any form), all controls it contains in 'Controls' will be disposed, even if you are using them elsewhere. To prevent this, remove the controls you want to preserve from the RoomDesigner Controls collection before it is closed.

Comment: I added this and it works: `private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewRoom.RoomID = textBox2.Text;
            NewRoom.Panel = RoomDesignerPanel;
            Global.Aquinas.Aquinas.Add(NewRoom);
            this.Controls.Remove(RoomDesignerPanel);
            this.Dispose();
        }`

Comment: this.Dispose will dispose your form. I'm not so sure you want to do that

Comment: I need to get rid of that form as I need to make new ones each time I want to add a room. Unless there's a better way, such as resetting the form. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: As long as any controls that you need to use later are not part of the disposed form's Controls collection, there is no problem. Just be aware